# How can I open specific ports for my Apache server?

Tags: apache2

How can I open specific ports for my **apache** server under linux?
I'm trying to build a connection with a online game that sends messages and receives to a specific port. I want to make my apache server/linux machine to listen to that specific port. bottom line, being able to receive/send data from/to that port

Comment: Is this about allowing incoming connections to specific ports Apache is already listening to or are you asking about configuring Apache to listen on specific ports?

Please provide information when asking questions - in its current state your question is too vague.

Comment: I changed the question. Hope it's clearer now. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at binding Apache to specific ports [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html).

I assume you're aware that you don't normally choose the port from which you're sending data, unless this is in a response to an already established connection.

For example, to make the server accept connections on both port 80 and port 8000, on all interfaces, use:

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
```

To make the server accept connections on port 80 for one interface, and port 8000 on another, use

```
Listen 192.0.2.1:80
Listen 192.0.2.5:8000
```