# How to configure eth1

Tags: networking, ip

I need to set up `eth1` using these :

```
ip 10.5.15.200
netmast 255.255.255.128
mac address AA:6F:78:UI:34:34
```

and must be set up *before* `eth1` starts
and default gateway must be the first usable address from network

Comment: what do you mean with `first usable address from network`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and add the following content:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static 
  address 10.5.15.200
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  pre-up ifconfig eth1 hw ether AA:6F:78:UI:34:34
```

This sets the specific values. However at the moment it is unclear what you meant with your comment on the default gateway. Could you elaborate?

Comment: For MAC address it must be set up before the interface starts. All i know it's that i must use pre-up but i don't know how. Forget about the part with default gateway

Comment: I changed my answer it should reflect now your last comment.

Comment: Hey @Alex, if you find my answer helpful or it solves your problem, it would be nice to upvote it or to accent it as correct answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: I have one more question for you. Do you know how to make apache2 to listen only on port 8080

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/224415/236 for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway address can be any of the usable addresses within the 25 bit subnet here. It is usually the first, sometimes the last IPv4 address available.

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static 
  address 10.5.15.200
  netmask 255.255.255.128
  gateway 10.5.15.129
  hwaddress ether AA:6F:78:UI:34:34
```